# Change innerHTML of a php DOMElement

Tags: javascript

In fact during a JS script I change the innerHTML attribute of a DIV, and
this content itself contains JS code.

The problem: This code is not executed js on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute some javascript after the page loads, you need to insert it in the head of the document:

```
var script = document.creatElement('script');
script.src = "path to some script";
script.type = "text/javascript";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

or to use `eval()`

Comment: Please don't use `eval`, insert the script into the head instead.

Comment: Don't think only because it's a bad idea we shouldn't mention it. Yes, it should be avoided but if you know what you're doing it might be useful